# Извлечение определённых симловов из *.dmp файлов

Tags: c

Пытаюсь из дамп файла извлечь читаемые символы (к примеру буквы и цифры) и записать результат в *.txt файл. Написал вот такую программу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalnum(ch)) {
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Но в выходном файле обнаруживаю результат:

```
MDMPaZ4LD8DwBZrLRTZ2780832RTZ25B831HHGDgXwZ55Su2Z55
```

Если вместо `isalnum(ch)` подставить `1` (т.е. программа должна вывести все символы в файле), то она выводит:

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/25938/20180518-syte-22kb.jpg

В дамп файле свыше 39000 строк. Причем выводимые значения в первым случае действительно имеют место быть. Но по всей видимости, программа досрочно завершает работу, не дождавшись конца файла.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, куда копать?

UPDATE:
http://my.jetscreenshot.com/25938/20180518-rnuw-213kb.jpg
Я это мой дамп снятый с программы, которую я написал (по книге). В нём лежит вот такая вот строчка. Но мне её не отыскать т.к. в дампе 39000 строк, я через поиск справился, т.к. знал, что ищу. Мне нужно убрать бесполезные символы, и оставить в выходном файле только ancii символы. Тогда мне будет легче просмотреть, есть ли что-нибудь интересное.

Comment: Что такое .dmp файл ? memory dump file Windows  (файл малого дампа памяти Windows)?

Comment: Что-то я не понял, чего вы вообще хотите. Почему вы решили, что в дампе должно быть что-то читаемое?

Comment: @andreymal обновил пост, с пояснениями.

Comment: @JaponDemon верно.

Comment: На Linux утилита strings помогла бы.

Comment: Ага, теперь понял. Хотя в коде программы на первый взгляд ошибок не вижу

Comment: Гугл говорит, что EOF может означать ошибку, проверьте `ferror`

Comment: @JaponDemon Под windows можно busybox скачать. Там тоже есть strings.

Comment: @kisssko просто намекнул, но спасибо за инфу.